# Transform property causes artifacts

Tags: css

I have an element which needs to be a bit transform-translated on mousemove (like parallax i guess)
codepen.io/anon/pen/PJQqjW

But in Mozilla when i don't move the mouse, element has an artifact, the line in the middle of it.

What can be wrong?

Comment: `//here is some code to make a parallax om mouse move` What is this code?

Comment: Please post the **code in your question**. There is a reason why StackOverflow does not allow you to post links to external code hosting services without any code in your question (and it is very succinctly explained in the popover that comes along when you attempt to post your question).

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in firefox for this > https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818109

You can use some hax like translate3d but that would move your element slightly, and that's something i guess you won't like.

Also, the thing that is causing this bug is the fact that you use `179deg`, use `180deg` instead, and the problem seems to go away.

See snippet

```css
.triangle {
  border: 4vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 13vh solid red;
  width: 0;
  height: 32vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

**But** why don't you make the triangle rotated ( border-bottom instead of border-top )  in the first place ?

```css
.triangle {
  border: 4vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13vh solid red;
  width: 0;
  height: 32vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: it's just an example, what if i need if to be rotated 45deg or 90deg? ths issue still the same

Comment: @Kirill as i told you in my answer, this is a known bug that's happening in firefox among many other bugs that appear cross browser. There are workarounds for almost everything but those workarounds are not general, they are specific for the specific situation. You either rethink your approach , either you ' live ' with the bug. This is my oppinion